# tkinter canvas draw an oval canvas with the canvas width and height 30% of the size responsive

Tags: tkinter, ttk

```py
# Main style configs
self.appWidth = 500
self.appHeigth = self.winfo_screenheight() - 75
screenPosX = self.winfo_screenwidth() - self.appWidth - 10
        
self.geometry(f'{self.appWidth}x{self.appHeigth}+{screenPosX}+0')
```

```py
self.tableContainner = Canvas(self)
    self.tableContainner.place(relx=0,rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5) 
    Create Table
    print(self.winfo_depth())
    self.tableContainner.create_oval(0,0,self.appWidth,self.appHeigth/2.5, fill='blue')
```

I'm trying to make an oval circle with the width of my app, and the height of 30% of it trying to make it responsive like the attributes found in 'place' relx rely etc, I've already tested them all but it's possible to use some winfo_* to find out what realtime window size and change canvas size when changed?

Or simply fill the entire canvas which in this case is already responsive...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the oval once, then create a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the canvas to call a function that resizes the oval. The `<Configure>` event fires whenever the canvas changes size.

The following example creates a canvas half the height of the window, and then draws an oval the full width and 1/3 the height, which will resize whenever the canvas changes size.

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.tableContainer = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.tableContainer.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)

        self.tableContainer.create_oval(0, 0, 1, 1, fill='blue', tags=("oval",))
        self.tableContainer.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_oval)

    def resize_oval(self, event):
        width = event.width
        height = event.height
        self.tableContainer.coords("oval", 0, 0, width, height*.30)
```